# Wi-Fi is not turning on

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, wifi-configuration, compaq-laptop

I have HP Compaq Presario Q57 with Windows 10 installed. It was running smooth, suddenly Wi-Fi stopped turning on, and Bluetooth option is also unavailable, not even in Settings.

Comment: You might have inadvertently statrted Airplane Mode. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027421/windows-turn-airplane-mode-on-or-off

Comment: no airplane mode isn't turned on